# Facebook Messenger Bot resends page welcome message each time user sends message

Tags: express, facebook-messenger, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I've created a Facebook messenger bot that works as expected and sends a few automated replies based on user input. However, when I connected the bot to an ad, I began having trouble.

Facebook requires a message dialogue to be initialized each time the message window is opened via an ad click (See below). This script has no connection to the server which my bot lives on. However, whenever a user responds to the bot, the welcome text (specified below) is called along with the response from my server.

Is this just default FB behavior? Is there a way to disable it? Something I'm doing wrong?

In the ad creation GUI I set up the message that will be displayed when the user clicks the ad using the following interface:

[image: Ad Builder]

I can then customize the response using either the GUI or my own JSON (I've tried both):

[image]

Comment: can you post the code that sends the welcome message, including any conditionals that get to it?

Comment: @amuramoto The code that sends the message is on FB's end. I don't believe I have access to any of the conditionals. I attached images of the GUI used to create the message.